# works in all browser except Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tried everything. It works on Chrome,  Vuze and Opera. But not on FirefoxThe code for the PHP file is this:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM `tarotAntwoord` WHERE `kaart` = '".$kaart."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$kaarter = utf8_encode ($row['kaart']);
echo $kaarter;

$test ="this is a  test";
echo $test;
```

I use this echo, for an ajax response in a modal.

The modal outputs

> this is a test

But it doesn't output the value `$kaarter` I got from the database.

It works in every browser except Firefox. (And it didn't work in chrome at my girlfriend).

Do I have to use an operator on the string from mysql or something? The Ajax script works, because it displays the test variable. I've tried with and without the utf8 encode.

This is the client side. No error in chrome debugging (f12)

```
function hedenFunction(){

    var verleden = document.getElementById("tarot2").src;
 //   document.getElementById("verledenAntwoord").innerHTML = "hoi dit is een modal test";

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById("hedenAntwoord").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        };


    xmlhttp.open("GET","tarotantwoord.php?q="+verleden,true);
    xmlhttp.send();


}
```

Comment: So this is more a PHP question since you do get the other value right? Sounds a bit odd since PHP is server side so a different browser version doesn't matter. Suggest to turn debugging on and see what error you get.

Comment: I've seen this problem before, but first! Browser HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH the Server, NOTHING AT ALL, Browser is NEVER the reason for PHP code not working, unless you explicitly told it to. --- Now then, your problem is related to AdBlocker, it blocks the modal, at least that's what my users experienced some time ago.